# Displaying sorted results of a web crawl

Tags: python, sorting, web-scraping

The issue I have with this class is that most of the methods are almost the same. I would like for this code to be more pythonic.

Note: I plan on replacing all the `for` loop constructs with list comprehensions.

```
class Sorter(BaseCrawler):

    def __init__(self, base_dir):
        self.base_dir = base_dir

    def by_size(self, *options):
        '''
        Sort files by size
        '''
        file_list = []
        for fn in self.files(*options):
            file_list.append((fn, float(os.path.getsize(fn))))
        file_list.sort(key=lambda fn: fn[1])
        return file_list  

    def by_mtime(self, *options):
        '''
        Sort files by modified time.
        '''
        file_list = []
        for fn in self.files(*options):
            file_list.append((fn, os.path.getmtime(fn)))
        file_list.sort(key=lambda fn: fn[1])
        return file_list  

    def by_ctime(self, *options):
        '''
        Sort files by creation time.
        '''
        file_list = []
        for fn in self.files(*options):
            file_list.append((fn, os.path.getctime(fn)))
        file_list.sort(key=lambda fn: fn[1])
        return file_list  

    def by_atime(self, *options):
        '''
        Sort files by access time.
        '''
        file_list = []
        for fn in self.files(*options):
            file_list.append((fn, os.path.getatime(fn)))
        file_list.sort(key=lambda fn: fn[1])
        return file_list  

    def last_modified(self):
        '''
        Return the last modified file.
        '''
        return self.by_mtime()[0]   

    def last_accessed(self):
        '''
        Return the last accessed file.
        '''
        return self.by_atime()[0]   

    def last_created(self):
        '''
        Return the last created file.
        '''
        return self.by_ctime()[0]

    def average_fsize(self):
        '''
        Return the average file size.
        '''
        sizes = []
        for name, size in c.by_size():
            sizes.append(size)
        return sum(sizes) / len(sizes)

    def above_avg_size(self, times):
        '''
        Yield files that have an above average file size.
        '''
        avg = self.average_fsize()
        for f, s in c.by_size():
            if s > avg * times:
                yield f, s
```

Answer (score 5):

Removing duplication is a very worthy goal.  Just "factor out" the feature-extraction functions ("f-e-f"s):

```
import operator

class Sorter(BaseCrawler):

    def __init__(self, base_dir):
        self.base_dir = base_dir

    def _sort(self, fef, *options):
        file_list = [(fn, fef(fn)) for fn in self.files(*options)]
        return sorted(file_list, key=operator.itemgetter(1))

    def by_size(self, *options):
        def fef(fn): return float(os.path.getsize(fn))
        return self._sort(fef, *options)

    def by_mtime(self, *options):
        return self._sort(os.path.getmtime, *options)
```

etc, etc.

Not sure why `by_size` needs that `float` rather than the natural `int` returned by `os.path.getsize` (I'd rather do the `float` cast, if needed, downstream), but I've kept that dubious choice to show how best to deal with a f-e-f that's not already a plain existing function (hint: **not** with a `lambda`:-).

Other improvements are feasible which don't deal with duplication but with efficiency.  For example, consider:

```
def last_modified(self):
    '''
    Return the last modified file.
    '''
    return self.by_mtime()[0]
```

this does a lot of work (list building and sorting) that it doesn't need to do (and actually does **not** meet its name and docstring: it returns the file modified **earliest**, because the sort in `by_mtime` is in ascending order).  How much simpler to do...:

```
def last_modified(self):
    '''
    Return the last modified file.
    '''
    return max(self.files(), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

(this one fixes the bug; to maintain the bug, use `min` in lieu of `max`).

Answer (score 3):

Since functions are objects too, you can create a mapping to use and replace the `by_` functions all with one function.

```
sort_choices = { 'size': lambda fn: float(os.path.getsize(fn)),
                 'mtime': lambda fn: os.path.getmtime(fn),
                 # ...
               }

def sorted_by(self, by, *options):
    file_list = [(fn, sort_choices[by](fn)) for fn in self.files(*options)]
    file_list.sort(key=lambda fn: fn[1])
    return file_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you find yourself writing almost the same code over and over, it's a strong clue that what you're doing might just be a special case of something more general. In this case you've got a lot of methods like that. After looking all of them over and noting how they vary, you can often reduce each one to a single call to a new generic method you'll write which can be supplied with arguments to tell which variation of the processing it needs to perform.

I've done that your sample code and decided to add a new generic function named `_apply()` to perform the repetitious code. It has a leading underscore character to indicate it's a private method not meant to be called from outside the class. It's arguments are a function to call to get the path attribute, and lastly a list of options to pass on to the `self.files()` method not shown.

I did the same sort of analysis on the `last_modified()`, `last_accessed()`, and `last_created()` methods which resulted in the addition of another new generic method named `_last_time()` being added. Afterwards it enabled the rewriting of the latter them methods.

That kind approach wasn't applicable to the remaining `average_fsize()` and `above_avg_size()` methods, but it is possible to optimize them a bit as shown.

```
import operator

class Sorter(BaseCrawler):

    def __init__(self, base_dir):
        self.base_dir = base_dir

    # added
    def _apply(path_attribute, *options):
        '''
        Get and sort path attribute using supplied function
        '''
        file_list = [(fn, path_attribute(fn)) for fn in self.files(*options)]
        file_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))  # sort by the attributes
        return file_list

    # added
    def _last_time(self, path_time_attribute):
        '''
        Get lastest path time attribute using supplied function
        '''
        return max(self.files(), key=path_time_attribute)

    def by_size(self, *options):
        '''
        Sort files by size
        '''
        filesizes = self._apply(os.path.getsize, *options))
        # convert the file sizes to float before returning
        return [(fn, float(sz)) for fn, sz in filesizes)]

    def by_mtime(self, *options):
        '''
        Sort files by modified time.
        '''
        return self._apply(os.path.getmtime, *options)

    def by_ctime(self, *options):
        '''
        Sort files by creation time.
        '''
        return self._apply(os.path.getctime, *options)

    def by_atime(self, *options):
        '''
        Sort files by access time.
        '''
        return self._apply(os.path.getatime, *options)

    def last_modified(self):
        '''
        Return the last modified file.
        '''
        return self._last_time(os.path.getmtime)

    def last_accessed(self):
        '''
        Return the last accessed file.
        '''
        return self._last_time(os.path.getatime)

    def last_created(self):
        '''
        Return the last created file.
        '''
        return self._last_time(os.path.getctime)

    def average_fsize(self):
        '''
        Return the average file size.
        '''
        filesizes = c.by_size()  # list of filename, size pairs
        return sum(fs[1] for fs in filesizes) / len(filesizes)

    def above_avg_size(self, times):
        '''
        Yield files that have an above average file size.
        '''
        # doesn't call self.average_fsize() to avoid getting a file sizes twice
        filesizes = c.by_size()  # list of filename, size pairs
        avg = sum(fs[1] for fs in filesizes) / len(filesizes)
        for fn, sz in filesizes:
            if sz > avg * times:
                yield fn, sz
```

Comment: You can, alas, generalize **too** much: if you have any `options` to `by_atime`, the first one will be used as argument `result_type` and thus called as a function, likely resulting in a crash.

Comment: @Alex: Good point -- but fortunately fairly easy to fix in this instance by simply requiring callers -- which should all be defined within the class -- to always explicitly supply a value for the `result_type` argument. Despite the possibly of mistakes of this kind, wouldn't you agree that this is a valid, useful, (not to mention common approach)? It's what Author Martin Fowler, et al., call "refactoring" in their _Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code_ book.

Comment: There are many forms of refactoring, and one can go overboard.  All those `None`s in almost all cases weigh down the code's legibility, and thus are an inferior alternative to the much sharper choice of just requiring callers to provide a feature extraction function as in my answer -- look at how much simpler my A's `_sort` is wrt yours' `_apply`!  My approach ends up with **one** caller needing a local `def` (and it's dubious that even that is needed, as I still don't see why `int` is not just as good as `float` there!-).  Root cause: "feature extraction function" has real semantics itself...

Comment: @Alex: Yes, I see what you're saying and agree about maybe having gone too far on the abstraction by including the type conversion in it, too -- especially since it would be only be used in one somewhat nebulous situation. Removing it allows `_apply` to be simplified to point where it's pretty "legible" in my opinion -- so the superiority of what you did is less obvious IMHO. Encouraged by this, I went ahead and applied the approach to several more methods just for good measure. Thanks for your input -- all points duly noted.

Comment: Getting closer and closer to my A, I see.  So for example where I have `return self._sort(os.path.getmtime, *options)` you now have `return self._apply(os.path.getmtime, *options)` -- almost identical except that the name of the auxiliary method I used yesterday hints at the fact that it's chiefly responsible for sorting, while yours as of 15 minutes ago is extremely generic.  In one other minor issue, your `_apply` is three lines including a bedraggled `lambda` -- mine is 33% smaller and uses faster, well-designed `operator.itemgetter`.  Sorry, I still fail to see how your A is better...

Comment: @Alex: Yes, my version is still more abstract in that it combines or factors out both the feature extraction and the sorting, and the name of the generic method could probably be better. Actually I think our answers are probably more similar than different -- especially now -- and of course must concede to your legendary expertise. (Although the case you make about three lines vs two seems pretty insignificant and is countered by the fact it's accomplishing more).

Comment: How's your `_apply` "accomplishing more" than my `_sort`?  Yes, they're becoming closer with every edit of yours, but I'm still properly using `sorted` while you make do with `.sort`.  Ah well, SO is starting to grumble about "extended discussions in comments" so I guess this is my last comment here -- don't wanna get into chat!-)

Comment: @Alex: It accomplishes more because it handling both what you're calling feature-extraction as well as sorting of results. Sure, I considered using `sorted()` instead the `sort()` method, but chose the latter since it avoids the creation of an a new list. Unfortunately such in-place operations typically don't return values, so a separate `return file_list` statement became necessary -- as well as a trivial third line to return the sorted object. As I said, that one extra line seems of little importance -- a miniscule amount of extra code and "complexity" easily absorbed by most folks.